# Content is not filter with conceptual filter in views

Tags: views

I am using two view one view as a page with exposed filter and  another view as a block and filter the content by getting Value from url in  contextual filter.

Exp:http://exp.com/?field_project_catagory_tid=112&field_nd_portfolio_tid=92

If we use one conceptual filter this http://exp.com/field_project_catagory_tid=112

and  get the value with use the PHP code in conceptual filter

$path=drupal_get_path_alias($_GET["field_project_catagory_tid"]);
return $path;

Its working fine and listed the value in both the views

If  we pass one more filter then we have url Like this 
 http://exp.com/?field_project_catagory_tid=112&field_nd_portfolio_tid=92
and it works collectively fine.

but if user filter with one filter it is not working.

Then how we can use the value in contextual filter for individually also. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use **all** instead of id in any one parameter if you want to consider only one parameter.
e.g. like

```
http://exp.com/?field_project_catagory_tid=112&field_nd_portfolio_tid=all
```

or

```
http://exp.com/?field_project_catagory_tid=all&field_nd_portfolio_tid=112
```

Comment: thanks for reply.
let me know how we can use the all in conceptual filter because it will comes from exposed filter, and getting from url with 

PHP code

$path=drupal_get_path_alias($_GET["field_project_catagory_tid"]); return $path;